# Determine if mobile device is on a moving airplane?

Tags: android, ios, gps, accelerometer, cellular-network

I am wondering if there might be a good way to determine if a mobile device is powered on and located on a flying airplane.  Could a solution be generalized for both iOS and Android platforms?  Could position, altitude, and speed be determined at a minimum altitude?  Would gps be required?  Would localization via cel tower info be adequate?

Something like:

```
if (altitude > 100ft off ground) && (speed > 200 mph) then flying = true
```

Would not be perfect, but might be acceptably accurate.

Why:  I wonder if aggregate data representing whether a mobile device was powered on during takeoff or landing an airplane could be gathered.

Requirement: If a solution provided data for even a small percentage of mobile devices, the aggregate information might be considered significant in terms of determining if having such devices powered on during flight poses an aviation risk.  This would remove hearsay and anecdotal experience from the discussion.  Might help to make an argument that changes policy.

Please try to focus your response towards the technical considerations that would be in play here.  Would device owners have to necessarily download an app and opt in for this information to be known?  Would cel tower data somehow be enough?  Might more than one approach work?

Comment: on airplanes you should not use mobile devices. :)

Comment: How do you get this on their phone and convince them to run it and leave it running? They'd have to know, otherwise, you're violating privacy. Collecting GPS information is strictly passive, and would not be harmful anyway, as long as you're not trying to map the data. Can you even collect the raw GPS data?

Comment: Good points.  I feel a solution that simply identifies devices that had been accidentally left on would be ideal.  Having device owners opt-in might be problematic.  Using gps might indeed be limited by battery life for most devices.

Answer (score 1):

With GPS access you can determine position, direction, altitude and speed.  Be aware that the GPS in an iPhone will cause significant battery drain if left on indefinitely.

Comment: GPS data includes altitude.

Comment: I agree that a solution that requires "gps on" would be more accurate, but might not be effective with battery life being a limiting factor.

Comment: Beware; not all devices support altitude.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd rely on altitude from GPS anyway.

Comment: I imagine any solution that gives a binary result for is_flying is enough.  Perhaps such a solution would not require the positional accuracy used to navigate roads or sidewalks, but could still answer the question well.  No?

Comment: If that's all your looking for then yes, it should be sufficient.  There's mention of iOS CoreLocation not updating altitude reliably, so you might want to rank other factors higher (such as speed).

Comment: I wonder if the acceleration of takeoff could be reliably detected by device accelerometers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [911 Cell Phone Calls From Planes? Not Likely](http://rense.com/general56/cellpp.htm) and consider that aside from the cell signal not likely being received, the GPS signals probably have an even worse chance of getting through.

And BTW 100ft off which ground?  What are you using as a reference point?  There is a big difference between the altitude of Denver and that of the Dead Sea, and thats not even taking into consideration the fact that the earth isn't perfectly round.

Comment: Well, with gps on, a device could know it's own altitude and velocity.  The device owner would then be in a position of having to decide whether or not to share the information.  The device owner would effectively be admitting they violated the FAA policy too.  My feeling is this development strategy would not yield the best possible result.  Perhaps pursuing a data trail that reveals 'accidentally left on' mobile devices would work better?

Comment: @PerryHorwich  Did you read the part of the link that points out that planes are basically big flying faraday cages?

Comment: Yes.  An interesting and relevant link.  Thanks.  Even so, my accidentally left-on iPhone 4 received a text message alert during final approach to Detroit at an altitude of at least 500 feet.  Just knowing if a device was on during take-off or landing might be adequate here.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it out with my iphone 4:

You will not receive GPS in a normal airplane.
Cell Tower location is also not working.

So remains only **accelleration sensors**.

This works, if you are clever enough :-).

You could recognize the high accelration at start, which outperforms any vehicle.
And even after start  you could recognize "typical" patterns of acceleration values.
Same applies for landing, this huge negative acceleration holding one for a long time is unique, too.

(But this is a major project, about 2-3 months for an experienced developper).
You would use `FFT` and frequency analysis for this task.

(There are companies they already do that: they can analyze which transportation vehicle type was used in a parcel service, where a special parcel contains an acceleration sensor.)